# Java Postcard Class and printer

Tags: java

I am trying to make a class and a separate printer class for post cards. The idea is to make a postcard that can take user inputs for sender, recipient, and occasion. Then add in something that allows us to send the same postcard to another friend. This is my post card class

```
public class Postcard
    { 
      private String message;
      //define other variables that you need in this class
      private String sender;
      private String recipiant;
      private String occasion;
      private String print;
      // Methods go here
      public Postcard()
      {
          String message = "Happy holidays too ";
          String sender = "Michael";
          String recipiant = "";
          String occasion = "";
      }
      public void setmessage(String m)
      {
          this.message = m;
      }
      public void setSender(String s)
      {
          this.sender = s;
      }
      public void setRecipiant(String r)
      {
          this.recipiant = r;
      }
      public void setOccasion(String o)
      {
          this.occasion = o;
      }
      public String print()
     {
          print = message + sender + recipiant + occasion;
          return print;
     }
}
```

and this is the post  card print class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PostcardPrinter
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String text = "Happy Holiday to ";//write your msg here
      Postcard myPostcard = new Postcard(); // use the constructor method
      //use the mutator method to set the name of the recipient
      Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
      String recipant = op.nextLine();
      String sender = op.nextLine();
      String occassion = op.nextLine();


      myPostcard.print();

      //write the code to send the same msg to another friend
      System.out.println("Do you want to send another? Type 'yes' or 'no' ");
      String choice = op.nextLine();
      while (choice != no)
      {   
        String text = "Happy Holiday to ";
        Postcard myPostcard = new Postcard(); 
        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
        String recipant = op.nextLine();
        String sender = op.nextLine();
        String occassion = op.nextLine();
      }
   } 
   }
```

Error's appear in the while loop saying that varriable no doesn't exist and when commented out, nothing happens. Virtual machine is running, but nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems to be a *Java* question, not *JavaScript*.  Re-tagging.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
while (choice != no)
```

Is looking for a *variable* called `no`,  not a *string constant*.  You want:

```
while (!choice.equals("no"))
```

Or, the case-insenstive method:

```
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
```

One thing to point out - since the value of `choice` never changes once inside the loop, you'll basically be looping forever.  You'll probably want to *ask again* after each iteration of the loop.  You can probably just set the initial value of *choice* to an empty string, then immediately start the loop when the program begins.  This would allow you to remove the redundant code above the loop.